# how to set permission chmod 777 programatically in android?

Tags: android, linux, file-io, permissions, chmod

I want to change the permission programatically in android of the folder `/data/system/dropbox` so, I have tried it by using

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su chmod 777 /data/system/dropbox");
```

but it is throwing `permission denied exception(FileNotFoundException)`

Answer (score 1):

for that your phone must be rooted...
after that you can change the permission ..

Comment: I have given as try {
                //Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su chmod 777 /data/system/dropbox");
                Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(pr.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p7 /data/system/dropbox \n");
                os.writeBytes("chmod 777 /data/system/dropbox \n");
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Even then it is displaying Permission denied(FileNotFoundException)

Comment: Can you access the data folder in your device..? if no then your device must be rooted...i hope, u know the root word... if u don't know, then google "how to root android device?"

Comment: I'm able to access system/app folder and device is rooted